# Get user_checkins from facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was trying to get user_checkins from facebook using graph api using the following code

```
https://graph.facebook.com/".$userId."/checkins?access_token=$accessToken
```

but I am getting a null array. I have added some checkins to my timeline but that's not showing up in the array. I have given the permissions for the access token.

Can someone help me out, thanks in advance.

Comment: print the complete url with the value of `$userId` and `$accessToken` and run in browser. and check that what is the result?

Comment: its the same null
    {
   "data": [
      
   ]
}

Comment: that means your parameter $userID or $accessToken are not correct.

Comment: userid and access token are correct, I also tried the graph api explorer from my login, its also giving me the null array. But I can see my checkins in my timeline

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1 :** In Facebook app version 2.4 user checkins are deprecated, but we can get them in either following way!

1. Get "user_posts" permission from your facebook app
2. the value of "type" should be "status"
3. the value of "status_type" should be "mobile_status_update"

Based on point 2 and 3 above you can put condition and acquire "user_checkins"

NOTE : I checked out from Mobile and Also from desktop and in both case the "status_type" is "mobile_status_update"

**Option 2 :** You can fire Graph api query like below

```
me?fields=posts{story,place}
```

Based on place field you can put condition to acquire "user_checkins"

let me know if you this is helpful.